# Propagation of network printer among non-domain user

Tags: printer, network-printer, windows-server

I work at small company and I want to establish Windows Server, as well as transfering every user of every computer to server domain. But as novice in administration, I would like to know, how is it possible to propagate network printer among users that brings their laptops from home, so I will get rid of installing drivers on each device. It seems impractical to create domain user on every employees personal device, especially when they may get nervous about me doing something with their laptops.

What solutions may I implement to this situation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without a driver install? It doesn't work that way. The driver has to be on the computer by some method to allow the computer to talk to the printer.

Enterprise does this by preloading the drivers or packaging and sharing them from a source trusted within the enterprise.

Some printers share their drivers via Windows Update, and so unmanaged computers can easily get them themselves without requiring action on the users part.

So your solutions are to set up a domain and manage the computers, or use a printer that publishes its drivers via Microsoft update.